# short cut for going back to previous implementations in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using the Intellij to view the codes.

I usually use `ctrl` + `B` to go to declaration and find the detailed implementations of the codes. However, I have no idea about going back to previous position where I started. So, I clicked the tab whenever I want to go back to the previous screen and this behavior is very annoyed and time consuming tasks. Do you know the short-cut of how to go back previous screen to debug the codes more quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to next/previous editor tab

> Alt + Right/Left

Navigate back/forward codes

> Ctrl + Alt + Right/Left

Also [Navigating Through the Source Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/navigating-through-the-source-code.html) will help you.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Right/Left didn't work. I am using the Intellij on the virtual box. When I input Ctrl + Alt + Right/Left, the display ask me to switch the panel of the virtual box...

Comment: You can change virtual box key combination for panel switch with something else "right shift + right ctrl" so it doesn't matter for you.

Comment: Or you can change shortcuts in IntelliJ.